# Manually editing Angular query parameters in URL and then loading page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angular doesn't respond when I directly edit the query parameters in the URL of my browser. For example,

Changing:

`/view?page=1`

To:

`/view?page=2`

Then pressing 'ENTER' in the browser doesn't do anything. Nothing happens. I expected the page to load with the new query parameters. Something in Angularjs must be stopping it?

The expected behavior would be like this:

Change:

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs?page=1`

To:

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs?page=2`

Press ENTER in browser and browser will load data for page 2.

I don't think it is my route:

```
$stateProvider.state('view', {
    url: '/view',
    controller: 'DemoCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'views/demo.html'
})
```

How can I allow the user to manually edit the query parameters and have it load in the browser?

**EDIT**

```
// route
$stateProvider.state('view', {
    url: '/view?page',
    controller: 'DemoCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'views/demo.html'
})

// controller
angular.controller("DemoCtrl", ['$scope', '$stateParams',
    function($scope, $stateParams) {
        // stuff
    })
]);
```

Comment: Does the URL ends up with a hash, such as `domain#something?params` ? If so, you actually only change the hash and I believe browsers don't fully reload the page but instead repaint it and call some onhashchange event.

Comment: So where you have "//stuff" in the controller. if you change that to console.log($stateParams.page); then do you see the page you passed in the console? What else is it supposed to do beyond that...?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using `ui-router`? If so, you need to tell it to allow the `page` parameter like this:

```
$stateProvider.state('view', {
    url: '/view?page',
    controller: 'DemoCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'views/demo.html'
})
```

Then in your controller you must inject `$stateParams` and then you can access the page with `$stateParams.page`

Comment: Yes, I am using `ui-router`. Can you explain what you mean by injecting `$stateParams`? Where would I do the injecting if the user is editing the URL in their browser and then pressing ENTER? Am I supposed to do a $watch or something?

Comment: Just how you would inject any dependency into a controller: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di At least for me in html5mode when I change the URL in the location bar of the browser it's a fresh request so the controller is totally re-loaded from scratch so a $watch is unnecessary, but that's another question.

Comment: Oh okay. I made some edits (see post), but still nothing happens when I edit the URL in the location bar.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look on ngRoute
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route